# Can I do HTTP Digest Authentication with varnish

Tags: authentication, access-token, varnish, digest-authentication

I am trying out Varnish to do HTTP digest authentication as well as manage tokens. Is it possible to do this in Varnish. Currently I am trying Varnish 4.x

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a [repository of external vmods](https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmods) you can use with some interesting choices like [basicauth](https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmod/basicauth), [authentication](https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmod/authentication) or [digest](https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmod/digest).

Answer (score -1):

Varnish 4 does not support VMOD Digest. It is just for Varnish 3.

Comment: Could you add some "proof" of this?